# Setting up a Docker registry with Letsencrypt certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04, docker-registry, lets-encrypt

I'm setting up a domain registry as described here:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

I generated a certificate for docker.mydomain.com and started the docker using their command on my server:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

I've started the docker and pointed to certificates I obtained using letsencrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/).

Now, when I browse to https://docker.mydomain.com:5000/v2/ I will get a page with just '{}', with a green lock (succesful secure page request).

But when I try to do a `docker login docker.mydomain.com:5000` from a different server I see a error in the registry docker:

```
 TLS handshake error from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:51773: remote error: bad certificate
```

I've tried some different variations in setting up the certificates, and gotten errors like:

```
remote error: unknown certificate authority
```

and

```
 tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker seams to not support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) : https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9969

Update : Docker now should support SNI.

It's mean, when connecting to your server during the tls transaction, the docker client do not specify the domain name, so your server show the default certificate.

The solution could be to change to default certificate of your server to be to one valid for the docker domain.

This site works only in browsers with SNI support.

To check if your (sub-)domain works with clients not SNI-aware, you can use ssllabs.com/ssltest : If you DONT see the message, "This site works only in browsers with SNI support. " then it will works.

Comment: My server is running ssl on www.mydomain.com, so I need to point to that certificate and then set the docker on another port, like www.mydomain.com:5000 ?

Comment: Got it working now, but according to your link and the comments, subdomains should work as well? Anyhow thanks for answering, I can continue now.

Comment: SNI works that way : SNI-aware client send unencrypted the name of the domain. SNI-aware server use that information to decide which certificate to show. If the client is not SNI-aware, the server have no way to decide which certificate to show. In most case, the server will show the first certificate declared, so client that are not SNI-aware will only works on the domains listed in that certificate. If that certificate contains also subdomains or is wildcard, it will works.

Comment: To check if your (sub-)domain works with clients not SNI-aware, you can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest : If you DONT see the message, "This site works only in browsers with SNI support. " then it will works.

Comment: SNI is supported in Docker now.

Comment: @JustinCormack from which version?